# Input timing not supported - change input timing to 1600x900, 60 Hz on Ubuntu 22.04 installation on Lenovo ST550 Server

Tags: graphics, display, 22.04

We have freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) over the Lenovo server ST550. However, as soon as the server was installed with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version, none of the monitors was able to support the screen display timing. We have uninstalled and reinstalled the OS. However, still, the same issue persists. Can anyone suggest how to get back the display? The monitor is from Dell.

Comment: You upgraded from Ubuntu Core 20 to Ubuntu 22.04? Only Ubuntu Core uses a single digit version. If this is not correct please EDIT and correct the question. Questions can only be answered based on the info given.

Comment: Not exactly remember the earlier version. This version was reinstalled from the Ubuntu website.

Comment: So it was not an upgrade but a fresh install? If that is correct please EDIT the question to reflect this.

Comment: corrected and edited the question

Comment: The question is unclear. How did you try to change timing? How is the monitor connected?

Comment: I have not changed anything. It is changed after the installation of the OS. Monitor is connected the same way as CPU is connected to the PC. Everything works fine when earlier version of OS was installed.